# codedeploy appspec.yml failed to copy files to destination

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-code-deploy, aws-codepipeline

**appspe.yml script:**

```
version: 0.0
os: linux
files:
  - source: /
    destination: /home/ubuntu/
permissions:
  - object: /home/ubuntu/
    owner: root
    group: root
    mode: 777
hooks:
  BeforeInstall:
    - location: scripts/install_dependencies.sh
      timeout: 300
      runas: root
    - location: scripts/start_server.sh
      timeout: 300
      runas: root
  ApplicationStop:
    - location: scripts/stop_server.sh
      timeout: 300
      runas: root
```

Unfortunately, it didn't copy the files to **`/home/ubuntu/`** directory. With this, I am getting the following error while deploying through codedeploy

> LifecycleEvent - BeforeInstall Script -
>   scripts/install_dependencies.sh Script - scripts/start_server.sh
>   [stderr]cp: cannot stat 'scripts/gunicorn.service': No such file or
>   directory [stderr]Failed to start gunicorn.service: Unit
>   gunicorn.service not found. [stderr]Failed to execute operation: No
>   such file or directory [stderr]Failed to restart gunicorn.service:
>   Unit gunicorn.service not found. [stderr]cp: cannot stat
>   'scripts/LIMA': No such file or directory [stderr]ln: failed to create
>   symbolic link '/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/LIMA': File exists
>   [stderr]ERROR: Bad port

What went wrong here?

Comment: How do I overwrite the existing files when new code is deployed? I added `overwrite:yes` in appspec.yml files section, but didn't work

Comment: Can you post the scripts to a gist? Are you trying to install unicorn and nginx? Looks like the dependencies script didnt run and caused the others fail.

Answer (score 3):

I faced the same issue. 
When I moved the commands in the "BeforeInstall" hook to the "AfterInstall" hook it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Your errors seem to be of the following categories:

1. Missing files.  ([stderr]cp: cannot stat 'scripts/gunicorn.service': No such file or directory).
   Debug: Check if the file actually exists in your deployment bundle. Check the bundle itself and the logs here: less /opt/codedeploy-agent/deployment-root/deployment-group-ID/deployment-ID/.  [See here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/deployments-view-logs.html)
2. Failure to create symlink because it already exists. ([stderr]ln: failed to create symbolic link '/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/LIMA': File exists). This is not related to file overwrite. Probably there is a 'ln' command somewhere in your script to create the symlink.
   Debug: Modify the script to test the symlink for existence and then create it.

I hope this helps.